# How to get Child Controller to access function in Parent Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-controller

I have a simple parent and child controller setup, i am trying to get my child controller to call a function in the parent controller:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Parent>

    <p ng-hide="ribbonHide">{{ribbonMessage}}</p>

    <div ng-controller="Child">


    </div>

</div>
```

Parent.js:

```
app.controller('Parent', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.searchRibbon = function() {
        return {
            default : function() {
                $scope.ribbonMessage = 'Welcome';
                $scope.ribbonHide = false;
            },
            clearMessage: function() {
                $scope.ribbonMessage = '';
            },
            hide: function() {
                $scope.ribbonHide = true;
            },
            autoRemove: function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.searchRibbon.hide();
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $scope.searchRibbon.clearMessage();
                    }, 500);
                }, 5000);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Child.js

```
app.controller('Child', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.$parent.searchRibbon.autoRemove();
});
```

With the above in place, i get the error:

```
TypeError: $scope.$parent.searchRibbon.autoRemove is not a function
```

Thanks

Comment: you can use controllerAs attribute

Comment: you also don't have a autoHide function...  the one you are calling

Comment: `searchRibbon` appears to be a function itself that returns an Object. So `$scope.$parent.searchRibbon().autoRemove()` should work, but that seems odd. Are you sure that you don't want `searchRibbon` to be a standard Object?

Comment: The child has access to the parent - so `$scope.searchRibbon().autoRemove()` should work.

Comment: @z.a. - it should have been autoRemove();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`searchRibbon` appears to be a function itself, which returns the Object that you're expecting. As such, `$scope.$parent.searchRibbon().autoRemove()` should work.

But that seems odd. Are you sure that you don't want `searchRibbon` to be a standard Object?

```
$scope.searchRibbon = {
    default : function() {
        $scope.ribbonMessage = 'Welcome';
        $scope.ribbonHide = false;
    }, // ... the other ribbon properties go here
}
```

If you need the scoping that the function provides, you might be after something more along the lines of:

```
$scope.searchRibbon = getSearchRibbon();

function getSearchRibbon() { // This should probably be in a Service
    return {
        default : function() {
            $scope.ribbonMessage = 'Welcome';
            $scope.ribbonHide = false;
        }, // ... the other ribbon properties go here
    }
}
```

Comment: i prefer the way you have demo'd above, however, how do i can 'default' from my child? $scope.parent.searchRibbon.default(); ??

Comment: Yep, `$scope.parent.searchRibbon.default();` if you flatten it to a simple Object. If you leave it as a function (as in your original solution), then it would be `$scope.parent.searchRibbon().default();`

Comment: yes ive flattened to a simple object... however i am still seeing: Error: $scope.$parent.searchRibbon.default is not a function

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that $scope.searchRibbon is a function. In which case, in the child, you will first need to first call the searchRibbon function, then call the hide function

```
$scope.$parent.searchRibbon().hide();
```

Or alternately, you could declare $scope.searchRibbon as an object, instead of a function (much easier and avoid scope issues).

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller('Parent', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.searchRibbon = {
      default: function() {
        $scope.ribbonMessage = 'Welcome';
        $scope.ribbonHide = false;
      },
      clearMessage: function() {
        $scope.ribbonMessage = '';
      },
      hide: function() {
        $scope.ribbonHide = true;
      },
      autoRemove: function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          $scope.searchRibbon.hide();
          $timeout(function() {
            $scope.searchRibbon.clearMessage();
          }, 500);
        }, 5000);
      }
    }
  })
  .controller('Child', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.$parent.searchRibbon.hide();
  });
```